# Clean up the each tags

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Tags in question: [each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/each) (x 1514), [.each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.each) (× 365) and [jquery-each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-each) (× 92)

All three claim to be about the jQuery `.each()` function. However, Ruby also has a `.each` method and underscore.js and mootools have there own `.each()` function.

I've retagged the questions that were not about jQuery from [.each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.each) to [each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/each) and made the description of the [each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/each) tag generic. This means a moderator can now easily merge [.each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.each) into [jquery-each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-each).

Comment: It looks like the opposite of what you asked happened, right? [tag:.each] got merged into [tag:each]